# Why is Shukra related to the Parashurama avatar of Vishnu in Jyotisha?

Tags: avatars, astrology, parashurama, shukra

Each planet in Jyotisha is associated with an avatar of Shri hari Vishnu in [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8_(%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%BE)). Why is Shukra Graha or Venus associated with the avatar of Shri hari Vishnu Parashurama?

> रामोऽवतारः सूर्यस्य चन्द्रस्य यदुनायकः। नृसिंहो भूमिपुत्रस्य बुद्धः
>   सोमसुतस्य च॥ ५॥
>
> वामनो विबुधेज्यस्य भार्गवो भार्गवस्य च। कूर्मो भास्करपुत्रस्य
>   सैंहिकेयस्य सूकरः॥ ६॥
>
> केतोर्मीनावतारश्च ये चान्ये तेऽपि खेटजाः ...

[Translation](http://www.libraryofyoga.com/handle/123456789/1058):

> 5-7. From Surya the incarnation of Rama, from Chandra that of Krishna,
>   from Mangala that of Narasimha, from Budha that of Buddha, from Guru
>   that of Vamana, from Shukra that of Parashurama, from Shani that of
>   Kurma (Tortoise), from Rahu that of Varaha (Pig) and from Ketu that of
>   Meena (Fish) occurred. All other incarnations than these also are
>   through the Grahas. The beings with more *Paramatmamsa* are called
>   divine beings.

Comment: Can you explain "from shani that of kurma and from Rahu that of Varaha.  Because varaha avatar happened before rahu was there.

Comment: Good question, but thats what Sage Parashara says, I think he is talking about the Rahu energy rather than a physical manifestation, which is independent of the timeframe.

Answer (score 3):

Shukra Graha or Venus is associated with spiritual ecstasy. This quality is very close to the character of Parashurama as explained by Shri PVR Rao in his video lectures:

> Parashurama was born to the sage Jamadagni. Jamadagni had a divine cow
>   called KamaDhenu. The  king KartaVirya wanted the wanted the cow for
>   himself and took it by force. Parashurama, enraged by this, killed the
>   king using his axe and killed all the warrior clan that belonged to
>   the king.
>
> In another incident, Jamadagni asks Parashurama to kill his mother.
>   His mother, Renuka was a devoted wife and used to go everyday to get
>   water from the river. One day, a few Gandharvas were visiting the river
>   and some temptation arose in her. The sage Jamadagni found this out
>   due to his yogic powers and asked Parashurama to kill her.
>   Parashurama, being very obedient to his father, went ahead and killed
>   his mother, without any delay. Being very pleased with this, his
>   father asked him what he wanted. Parashurama asked for a boon to bring
>   her mother back to life.

Here is the symbolic meaning explained in the lecture:

> Jamadagni represents the burning fire of Sadhana. When the spiritual
>   fire becomes strong, it gives rise to spiritual ecstasy (Parashurama).
>   Spiritual ecstasy (Parashurama) can only rise in one, when the
>   arrogance has been killed and purified. Here, the king KritaViraya,
>   represents the arrogance born out of brave deeds. When such ecstasy
>   rises, it kills and purifies and relative temptations arising due to
>   Maya (which is represented by Parashurama's mother). Also, such
>   ecstasy, kills and purifies all the *kshatriya* qualities in one like
>   revenge, anger etc. (represented by killing the warrior clan of the
>   king KritaVirya).

Also, the merciless nature of Parashurama, represents the Rajasic nature of Shukra Graha in its dealings.

PS: The above is not a word-to-word translation of the excerpt. For original lecture, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1McGPZvC2Uo

Comment: Are Pvr Rao & the author of the Jagannatha Hora software the same person?

Comment: Yes, indeed, he is an IIT Madras alumnus too

Comment: If Shukragraha is associate with comforts, beauty, female nature, wealth and luxury is it possible to connect this feature to Parashurama avatar also?